# Client testing/WireMock - A simple unit test to check whether the date conversion is performed correctly

Tags: java, unit-testing, http, junit, wiremock

I am trying to test a client library class, specifically the object mapper that converts the date format using `StdDateFormat`. I am using the StdDateFormat that Jackson provides to convert into the date format I want. All I want is to write a simple test but since this is client library, I need to use WireMock to mock the http server. How would I go about and test so that the date conversion is correctly done?

Here is the code I want to test (specifically, `.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat())` inside the MAPPER):

```
public class DefaultHttpClientUtil implements HttpClientUtil {
    private static final String FAILED_TO_PERFORM_HTTP_REQUEST = "Failed to perform HTTP request.";
    private static final String SERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION =
            "An error has occurred while serializing the payload to JSON";
    private static final String MISSING_URL = "Please provide a valid URL";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultHttpClientUtil.class);
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER =
            new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                    .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
                    .setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat())
                    .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

please let me know if more detailed are needed!

Comment: why not test that `MAPPER` generates the expected JSON?